# How to export only the selected layers in photoshop as individual png images

Tags: export, photoshop, layer

I want to be able to export only the selected layers in photoshop as individual png images (that are trimmed properly). I see the script to do all the layers in a PSD, but I only want to do the layers I've selected. Is this possible?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process ... btw, it took 5 seconds of Google search to find this answer. Might want to take a little more time and effort to research before asking such a general question. Hope the linked answer helps!

Comment: That question asks for ALL layers, I only want the SELECTED layers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you see that checkbox in the image they included? The one that says "Visible layers only"? That's at least a viable workaround, and have you tried the answer's script, there, to see if it can be adapted to your purposes?

Comment: @JasonM.Batchelor: The question is very clear, and it makes sense. If you don't know, please stop giving non-sense comments

Comment: Select the layers you like to have as png files and then right click in the layers panel and select the option for "Export as.." you will have all the layers that can be saved as png or other formats.

Answer (score 7):

One workaround for doing this would be:
1) Hide the layers you don't want to export
2) Use the usual File > Scripts > Export Layers to File and tick the "Visible layers only" option

hope that helps :)

Comment: I've tried that. It takes forever when you have hundreds of layers...

Comment: I don't even have that option

Comment: @OndrejRafaj in the new version of ps its change to separate option export in file menu